# TSQL show 1st April after next fiscal year

Tags: t-sql

I have the query below where the 1st July needs to be returned before the next fiscal year and then back to 1st April after next fiscal year . The query below keeps returning 01 July 2019 even after the next fiscal year.

```
select  (case when getdate() < '2020-03-31' then '2019-07-01' 
when GETDATE() > '2020-03-31' then
dateadd(month, 3, dateadd(year, datepart(year, dateadd(month, -3, '2021-05-26')) - 1900, 0)) end)
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in your `when` condition you are using `getDate()` which always returns today's date.

Try passing it as parameter:

```
Declare @Date date
SET @Date = '2021-05-26'
select  (case when @Date < '2020-03-31' then '2019-07-01' 
when @Date > '2020-03-31' then
dateadd(month, 3, dateadd(year, datepart(year, dateadd(month, -3, @Date)) - 1900, 0)) end)
```

Comment: I need to formulate this so it picks up the date every year rather than manually specifying.

Comment: @user3306489 how are you changing what `getDate()` returns?

Comment: Do you mean the datatype? I've not changed that

Comment: I plan to put the case statement in the where clause